# Sonarqube settings encryption

Tags: sonarqube, system-administration

I am attempting to setup sonarqube instance with HTTPS listener. I understand that sonarqube supports HTTPS out of the box in version 4.2. What I am having difficulty with is encrypting clear text passwords settings in the sonar.properties.

Looking at the their [wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Settings+Encryption) article about encryption support, it seems like it is possible to encrypt clear text passwords. However, I am not having any luck with encrypted value in sonar.web.https.keystorePass property. Tested with clear text and it works fine. Also tested different store types (JKS/PKCS12) or simpler passphrase, nothing seems to be working and keystore read fails when attempting to start the server with encrypted keystore password.

Was anyone able to use built in encryption mechanism in sonarcube to run it with HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the properties sonar.web.* can't be encrypted. This limitation is fixed in version 4.4 : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4781

Comment: Good to know. Looks like it is due for release as well. For now I have setup reverse proxy but will look forward to new version.